# Replace blank spaces and semicolon in Java with Regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to replace all strings that can contain any number of blank spaces followed by an ending ";", with just a ";"  but I am confused because of the multiple blank spaces.

```
"ExampleString1            ;" -> "ExampleString1;"
"ExampleString2  ;" -> "ExampleString2;"
"ExampleString3     ;" -> "ExampleString3;"
"ExampleString1 ; ExampleString1 ;" -----> ExampleString1;ExampleString1
```

I have tried like this: `example.replaceAll("\\s+",";")` but the problem is that there can be multiple blank spaces and that confuses me

Comment: @Eugene he wanted to have a single semicolon, not to remove the whole thing.

Comment: @AlexShesterov corrected... as an answer, thank you for spotting that and the OP showed he tried something btw...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
replaceAll("\\s+;", ";").replaceAll(";\\s+", ";")
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically do a match to first find

```
(.+?) ->  anything in a non-greedy fashion
(\\s+) -> followed by any number of whitespaces
(;) -> followed by a ";"
$ -> end of the string
```

Than simply drop the second group (empty spaces), by simply taking the first and third one via `$1$3`

```
String test = "ExampleString1            ;"; 
test = test.replaceFirst("(.+?)(\\s+)(;)$", "$1$3");
System.out.println(test); // ExampleString1;
```

Comment: If you only expect a single match per string, why use `replaceAll`? `replaceFirst` is enough.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew good point, edited

Comment: What if the string is like this:  "ExampleString1            ;     ExampleString1            ;"

Comment: @xmlParser what would be the expected result?

Comment: @Eugene "ExampleString1 ; ExampleString1 ;"    -----> ExampleString1;ExampleString1;

Comment: @xmlParser in such a case this becomes a lot easier `test = test.replaceAll("\\s", "");`

Comment: Sorry for the bad example. In this case: 
"Test String 1        ;TestString 2         ;" should be
"Test String 1;TestString 2;"
And if I go with replace all whitespaces it will be TestString1;TestString2

Comment: @xmlParser this is what my code does, have you tested it?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape the meta character `\s` like this:

```
"ExampleString1   ;".replaceAll("\\s+;$", ";")
```

Comment: If you only expect a single match per string, why use `.replaceAll`? `replaceFirst` is enough.

Comment: What if the string is like this:  "ExampleString1            ;     ExampleString1            ;"